# How can I create a searchbar like this?

Tags: css, animation, search, placeholder, smoothing

I really like the search bar on this website, https://www.marmosetmusic.com/

I can do it very basically using CSS steps animation but it doesn't look smooth and I have to change the timing based on the length of the placeholder.

Also, I am not sure how to overlay it as such over an image or parallax design.

What I have tried is:

HTML:

```
<title>Search</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/type-style.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />

    <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <h1>
  <i class='fa fa-anchor'></i>
  Test.com
</h1>
<div class='overlay'></div>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <form class='search'>
    <input placeholder="search..." required='true' type='text'>
    <button class='search-button'>
      <i class='fa fa-search'></i>
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans+SC:300,400);
body {
  background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16902/holidayphoto.jpg);
  background-position: 0 90%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 3.5em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Alegreya Sans SC', sans-serif;
  padding: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  opacity: 1;
}
h1 i {
  color: #e74c3c;
}

.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.92;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 560px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -280px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  z-index: 999999;
}

input[type="text"] {
  font-family: 'Alegreya Sans SC', sans-serif;
  width: 480px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #eee;
  background: #222;
  border: none;
  float: left;
  -webkit-transition: all 420ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 420ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 420ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 420ms ease-in-out;
}

input:focus {
  color: #fff;
  outline: none;
  background: #1a1a1a;
}

button[type="submit"], .search-button {
  border: 0;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #222222;
  border-left: solid 5px #222222;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  -webkit-transition: all 420ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 420ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 420ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 420ms ease-in-out;
}
button[type="submit"] i, .search-button i {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}

.search-button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.search-button:hover {
  background: #e53f2e;
  border-left: #e53f2e;
}

.switch-wrapper {
  font-family: 'Alegreya Sans SC', sans-serif;
  width: 70px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #444;
  right: 118px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 420ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 420ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 420ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 420ms ease-in-out;
}
.switch-wrapper:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: 'FLIGHT';
  line-height: 2.7em;
  left: -54px;
}
.switch-wrapper:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '+ HOTEL';
  line-height: 2.7em;
  right: -60px;
}
.switch-wrapper .switch {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  margin: 2px 2px;
  background: #222;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
.switch-wrapper .switch:hover {
  background: #282828;
}

.rent {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
}

.switch-wrapper.switched:after {
  color: #3498db;
  text-shadow: 0 0 4px #3498db;
  -webkit-transition: all 420ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 420ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 420ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 420ms ease-in-out;
}
.switch-wrapper.switched:before {
  color: #cfcfcf;
  -webkit-transition: all 420ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 420ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 420ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 420ms ease-in-out;
}

.switch-wrapper.not-switched:after {
  color: #cfcfcf;
  -webkit-transition: all 420ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 420ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 420ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 420ms ease-in-out;
}
.switch-wrapper.not-switched:before {
  color: #3498db;
  -webkit-transition: all 420ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 420ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 420ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 420ms ease-in-out;
}

.not-valid {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: #e74c3c;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 70px;
}

.not-valid span {
  font-family: 'Alegreya Sans SC', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 1.96em;
}
.not-valid span i {
  padding-right: 4px;
}
.not-valid span .error-close {
  color: #7b190f;
  float: right;
  padding: 7px 10px 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label.error {
  display: none !important;
}
```

JS

```
var s  = $('.switch');
var sw = $('.switch-wrapper');

$('input').on('click', function(a) {
  a.preventDefault();
});

function switchToggle() {
  s.stop(false,true).animate({left: "0"}, 200);
}

s.on('click', function() {

     if (sw.hasClass('switched')) {
       switchToggle();
     } else if (sw.hasClass('not-switched')) {
       s.stop(false,true).animate({left: "30px"}, 200);
     }

     sw.toggleClass('switched not-switched'); 
});

$('.search').validate({

   invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {

    var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();

    if (errors) {

      $("div.not-valid span").html("<i class='fa fa-warning'></i>  Please type search <i class='fa fa-times error-close'></i>");

      // Should use .stop() function.
      $(".not-valid").fadeIn();

      setTimeout(function() { 
          $(".not-valid").fadeOut();
        }, 2000);

      $('.error-close').on('click', function() {

        $(".not-valid").fadeOut();

      });

    } else {

      $(".not-valid").fadeOut();

    }

  }

});
```

All in one is found in [**this jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/kytsh2t5/) demo.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to stack-overflow, in this community you have to show what do you have tried and also you have to specify your issue clearly with some code samples.

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome, sure thing, let me dig it out!

Comment: In addition, I don't think it called a search bar, it is a search field! :)

Comment: Sorry, search field! It's late where I am and I do apologise, was up this morning at 6am so my brains turned to mush....

Comment: Aha! I've found it eventually, should I upload it to somewhere like JSFiddle?

Comment: you want the same thing exactly as the link you posted? using Firefox, i cannot see any animations on the searchField, only the Panels down of it, is this what you want?

Comment: Ok, so here's the basic version, I've lost the version with CSS steps, But I basically used what was on this website:http://designmodo.com/steps-css-animations/  
  
JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kytsh2t5/

Comment: @Rami.Q I'm using chrome, it peforms a "typing" animation with the place holder.

Comment: Rami.Q & sємsєм Thank you both for your replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example of how to style a search field in a similar manner as seen in your example. `display: flex` does most of the magic here, the rest is getting rid of backgrounds and borders or styling the submit button with an image

For the typing animation you should use a premade plugin like [typed.js](http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/)

```css
.search {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: flex;
}
.search input {
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.search input[type="text"] {
  flex: 1;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 2em;
}
.search input[type="submit"] {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 4px;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: url(https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-lines/39/search-512.png);
  background-size: cover;
}
.search input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <input type="text" name="search">
  <input type="submit" value="">
</div>
```